# Is there way in iOS to receive notification that a keychain entry has changed?

Tags: ios, iphone, callback, keychain

Is there way in iOS to receive notification that a keychain entry has changed?

I've seen that in OS X that there is a SecKeychainCallback mechanism but there is no indication that such an event-callback paradigm exists for the iPhone.

We are using the keychain to pass some token data between iOS apps, and it would be good if an app could receive a Notification if the data has changed, without continuously checking for it.

Comment: What about this? https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/1394998-seckeychainaddcallback

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unfortunately this isn't possible, Keychain Services on iOS is very barebones, and only provide simple APIs for accessing/storing items. And because it's C based, you won't be able to piggyback on any sort of KVO either.

You will need to poll at appropriate intervals.